# Why doesn't my second "Rows" field roll up into the first in PivotTable?

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table, olap-cube

I'm developing a cube, and using PivotTable to play with said cube.  I have this issue and I don't know if I'm seeing this because:

1. This is just the way it is, or
2. I'm missing something in my cube relationships, or
3. I'm missing something in excel.

I have a Kimball-like Date dimension that is role playing.  In my cube's Dimension Usage tab this dimension ("Document Create Date") has a referenced relationship to my "Document Count" fact table through the "Document" dimension.

In excel, I want to set up my PivotTable so that I can drill down in my rows through the dates and eventually into one of the "Document" dimension's fields (Document Number) only when I've gotten to the leaf level of the "Document Create Date" hierarchy.

Currently, when I add to the "Rows" area in PivotTable first the "Document Create Date.Calendar" hierarchy and next the "Document Number", all the Document Numbers always display.  They display in the correct area (ie: under the correct place in the Date Hiearchy) and the totals are ok, but they're all there.

Your help is, as always, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the way it is. If you add a hierarchy, its first level below the "All" member is always expanded. Of course, you can remove and add the hierarchy on demand, but if you add it, it will always be expanded in Excel pivot tables - as well as in most other client tools.

To get the behavior that you want, you could create a hierarchy (in whichever dimension you feel it would make sense, maybe a new one) that contains the levels of the date hierarchy, and below that a level containing the document number. But this would mean that you would have to replicate the date dimensions' attributes to the dimension containing this hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you, that saves me some grief.  I think that for my purposes the "Show Details" might be enough, but I'm going to try out Drillthrough actions, too.